# Freemarker: Iterate over a LinkedHashMap

Tags: freemarker

I have following piece of code -

```
public class Result {
    private Map<String, String> dataPoints = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

    public Map<String, String> getData() {
        return Maps.newHashMap(data);
    }

    public Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> getDataEntries() {
        return data.entrySet();
    }

    public void addData(final String key, final String value) {
        this.data.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

I am using LinkedHashMap as I want to maintain insertion order. I am trying to iterate over the map in my freemarker code as below. However, I get an exception.

```
<#if (result.dataPoints?keys?size > 0) >
    <#list result.getDataEntries() as entry>
        <tr>
            <td width="35%">
                <div>${entry.key}</div>
            </td>
            <td width="45%">${entry.value}</td>
            <td width="19%">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </#list>
</#if>
```

Exception:

```
Expression result.getDataEntries is undefined on line 50, column 24 in settings/settings-
diagnostics.ftl. The problematic instruction: ---------- ==> list result.getDataEntries() 
as entry [on line 50, column 17 in settings/settings-diagnostics.ftl] in user-directive 
printDiagnosticResult [on line 64, column 25 in settings/settings-diagnostics.ftl] in 
user-directive printDiagnosticResult [on line 76, column 13 in settings/settings-
diagnostics.ftl] in user-directive layout.landingbase [on line 1, column 1 in     
settings/settings-diagnostics.ftl] ---------- Java backtrace for programmers: ---------- 
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: Expression result.getDataEntries is undefined 
on line 50, column 24 in settings/settings-diagnostics.ftl. at 
freemarker.core.TemplateObject.assertNonNull(TemplateObject.java:124) at 
freemarker.core.TemplateObject.invalidTypeException(TemplateObject.java:134) at 
freemarker.core.MethodCall._getAsTemplateModel(MethodCall.java:114) at     
freemarker.core.Expression.getAsTemplateModel(Expression.java:89) at 
freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:94) at     
freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:208) at
```

If I replace above code with:

```
<#if (result.dataPoints?keys?size > 0) >
    <#list result.dataPoints?keys as key>
        <tr>
            <td width="35%">
                <div>${key}</div>
            </td>
            <td width="45%">${result.dataPoints[key]}</td>
            <td width="19%">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </#list>
</#if>
```

Any idea how do I iterate over the map so that I get the same order?

Comment: What's the problem with the last template?

Comment: @ddekany: The items returned by `result.dataPoints?keys` are not ordered as per insert operation. Even items returned by `result.dataPoints?values` are not insertion order compliant either.

Comment: It keeps the order for me. Doesn't `?key` returns some method or property named mixed with the keys? Because then I know what's the problem is...

Comment: And are you sure `dataPoints` is a `LinekdHashMap`? Because your Java example only has `data`, no `dataPoints`, so I can't see if what is it.

Comment: @ddekany: It's a typo, I have corrected my question. `?keys` did not return the elements in the same order as they were inserted. I get the desired order when I iterate using `entrySet()`.

Comment: Well, officially, it keeps the order, and it also does that for me. It would be good to find out what `ObjectWrapper` does your FreeMarker `Configuration` use. And note my other comment... you don't have method/property names mixed in, right?

Comment: (And you are still showing a `result.getDataEntries is undefined` error, which is unrelated.)

Comment: @ddekany: You are right, `?keys` does maintain insertion order. I was following the encapsulation paradigm wherein the getter method returned a new map. Instead of returning a `LinkedHashMap` instance, it was returning `HashMap` instance and thats what caused the order to change. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
<#if result.dataPoints?has_content >
    <#list result.dataPoints.entrySet() as entry>
        <tr>
            <td width="35%">
                <div>${entry.key}</div>
            </td>
            <td width="45%">${entry.value}</td>
            <td width="19%">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </#list>
</#if>
```

You may also need set object wrapper for `freemarker` template configuration. Like this:

```
BeansWrapper beansWrapper = (BeansWrapper) ObjectWrapper.BEANS_WRAPPER;
beansWrapper.setExposeFields(true);
config.setObjectWrapper(beansWrapper);
```

Where `config` is `freemarker.template.Configuration`.
If you using Spring Framework then extends `FreeMarkerConfigurer`:

```
public class FreeMarkerBeanWrapperConfigurer extends FreeMarkerConfigurer {
  @Override
  protected void postProcessConfiguration(Configuration config) throws IOException, TemplateException {
    super.postProcessConfiguration(config);

    BeansWrapper beansWrapper = (BeansWrapper) ObjectWrapper.BEANS_WRAPPER;
    beansWrapper.setExposeFields(true);
    config.setObjectWrapper(beansWrapper);
  }
}
```

Comment: Again, `?keys` meant to return the keys in the original order in the case of `LinkedHashMap`. I have tried it to be 100% sure, and it works here. So while this workaround might works, it would be better to spot the root of the problem.

Comment: @ddekany: I agree, I think I am missing something. I am trying to find the root cause.

Comment: @gotuskar: Maps will automatically be wrapped into a `SimpleHash` by freemarker if not implement `SortedMap`. `LinkedHashMap` don't implement `SortedMap` and will be wrapped into `HashMap`. As I say you need to use `BeansWrapper` to get all benefits from `LinkedHashMap`. You can read more about freemarker SimpleHash here: [SimpleHash](http://freemarker.org/docs/api/freemarker/template/SimpleHash.html)

Comment: I am no freemarker expert. However, base on what I have in place, I did not use `BeansWrapper` and I got the desired order output.

Comment: @seralex.vi: `SimpleHash` clones `HashMap`-s internally. Since `LinkedHashMap` is a `HashMap`, it will be cloned, which yields a `LinkedHashMap`, not a plain `HashMap`.

Comment: @ddekany: Yes, you are right. It's cloned and stay LinkedHashMap. Then it was very strange question)